# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code after updatin Xcode 15.0

Tags: flutter

After updating into Xcode 15.0  I am facing this issue.

I updated all ios files and use pod install and other options but did not work.

Search for the following line in your project, it must be in ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh file.

source="$(readlink "${source}")"
Replace that with:

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")" this way also did not work

Answer (score 0):

target→Build Phases→[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks

delete

[1]"${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-MyQuiz/Pods-MyQuiz-frameworks.sh"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).